# How can I access Documents folder of iOS App with C#

Tags: c#, iphone, .net, ios, windows

I want to push a file from Windows (c#) to an iPad and get it back later. I have no Network connection so I need to do this via USB cable.

I have found Manzana but seems not to support iTunes FileSharing.

Any hints ? I googled a lot but couldn't find anything useful.

There are some functions like "AMDeviceStartHouseArrest" but I don't know how to use them to get my Files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a way to get this done.

Thanks to a blogpost from Simon (http://blog.victornet.de/2011/04/10/c-manzana-iphoneipad-hausarrest/) and some Mails it finally worked.

I'm now using Manzana with the expansion from Simon:

```
MobileDevice.AMDeviceStartHouseArrestService(iPhoneHandle,      
MobileDevice.CFStringMakeConstantString(bundleIdentifier), null, ref hService, 0);
```

Starting the 'Housearrest' for a specific App (by bundleIdentifier) makes its '/Documents' Folder accessible via the default Manzana methods. So there is no need for jailbreaking the iDevice. Finally I'm able to push files to the iDevice and read them back.

Thanks again to Simon for the great support!

Comment: If you're still around, I'm having problems your solution to work. I've defined the method public static extern unsafe int AMDeviceStartHouseArrestService(void* device, void* identifier, void* unknown, ref void* handle, uint what); But when I ask for a list of directories it acts like I'm in Media/ instead of Documents/. Do you have any advice?

Comment: I've took a quick look into the code I used this. The following method is used to write a file with path `targetPath` to the devices documents folder with the name "somefilename.ext". I hope you can copy it (to tired for markup) and it answers your question. feel free to follow up.  `string pathOnDevice = @"/Documents/somefilename.ext";
...
public bool readFromDevice(string targetPath)
{
    if (_myIP.ReConnect("com.bundle.identifier"))
        Console.WriteLine("## Some debug output");
    else
        return false;
    _myIP.getFile(_myIP, pathOnDevice, targetPath);
    return true;
}`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. For posterity, I forked the library on GitHub and posted an example that uses the house arrest service to push a directory to the app sandbox (as opposed to the media folder). https://github.com/ImagineLearning-Public/MobileDevice

Answer (score 0):

Im not quite sure what you are asking. If you want to access standard files on an ipad, it can be set as a USB mass storage device. I believe the standard IO methods (System.IO) would then be able to read and write to the device, if you pass in the correct path. If you are talking about accessing an applications files, I do not believe this is possible due to security concerns with iOS (at least not in a standard, non-jailbroken way)

Comment: I'm talking about a SDK-conform way: iTunes-File-Sharing to access Documents-Folder of an App. I found some promising informations on itunesmobiledevice.dll and the mentioned 'HouseArrest' which seems to be an internal Name for this File-Sharing-Service. I'll be back as soon as I have more on that...